# C# dynamics and Expando object

Tags: c#, architecture, programming-practices, object-oriented-design

Under which application development scenarios C# dynamics and ExpandoObject can be used or when to consider using c# dynamics and ExpandoObject

Answer (score 3):

One scenario where I've seen dynamic used effectively was in the implementation of [feature toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html).

We had a globally accessible `FeatureToggles` class which was a dynamic object, therefore in our code we could make certain features of the code dependent on the toggle being enabled eg:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    if (FeatureToggles.SomeFeatureEnabled)
    {
        DoSomeFeature();
    }
}
```

The feature toggles were configured in the application configuration file, and the dynamic `FeatureToggles` object read the app config at startup. If a feature toggle was enabled in the config, the `FeatureToggles` class would return true; if a feature toggles was not enabled, **or was not yet in the configuration file**, the `FeatureToggles` class would return false. Crucially, this enabled us to start using feature toggles before they had even been configured*, in which case they defaulted to off.

* naturally there was logging output in this case.

Answer (score 3):

One edge case where `dynamic` is not necessary, but can make your code more DRY and not actually less type-safe is when implementing the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

The classical way to implement this is to have an `Accept(Visitor visitor)` method on each derived type and you have to implement it with the same `visitor.Visit(this)` boilerplate.

And this assumes the types in question support the visitor. If not, you need one big `if (obj is DerivedType1) … else if (obj is DerivedType2) … else if …` and modify it each time new type is added (along with adding the overload of `Visit()` for the new type).

With `dynamic`, it's a matter of single line to cast your type to `dynamic`, which means the correct overload will be chosen:

```
public void Visit(BaseType obj)
{
    VisitInternal((dynamic)obj);
}

protected virtual void VisitInternal(DerivedType1 obj)
{
}

protected virtual void VisitInternal(DerivedType2 obj)
{
}

// etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be my personal opinion but : Never

You are using C#. Static typed language. And probably one of the reasons why are you using it is because you like the safety of static typing for various reasons. If you wanted to sacrifice it, you would be using real dynamic language like Python or Ruby.

Comment: Why the down votes? I agree with @Euphoric: Do not use dynamics if you can avoid it.

Comment: This answer not constructive. There are cases where dynamics make sense, but using a different language is not an option. And the answer above was "never", not "if you can avoid it"

Comment: Apparently [Office interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) is one area where it makes your life much easier; it'd be at least one situation where opting for dynamic is the lesser of two evils.  Here's another [interop example](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Aug-11.html), although the use here is perhaps arguable.